# NullPointerException when working with in app billing?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have been recently trying to implement in app billing on a game I am working on, but I get a  NullPointerException and I just can't see why.

BuyActivity.java:

```
package com.liamw.games.whatami;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.liamw.games.whatami.util.IabHelper;
import com.liamw.games.whatami.util.IabResult;
import com.liamw.games.whatami.util.Inventory;
import com.liamw.games.whatami.util.Purchase;

public class BuyActivity extends Activity {

    String key, androidid;
    IabHelper mHelper;
    Button fifty;
    ProgressDialog wait;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // DONE Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy);

        fifty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b50hints);
        androidid = Secure.getString(BuyActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        final ProgressDialog wait = new ProgressDialog(this);
        wait.setTitle("Updating...");
        wait.setMessage("Please wait while the details are loaded...");
        wait.setCancelable(false);
        wait.show();

        key = "xxxxx";
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, key);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d("What Am I - IAB",
                            "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                }
                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!

                List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
                additionalSkuList.add("50hints");

                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
                        mQueryFinishedListener);

            }
        });

        fifty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(BuyActivity.this, "50hints", 10001,
                        mPurchaseFinishedListener, androidid);
                fifty.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error
                return;
            }

            String fiftyhintscost = inventory.getSkuDetails("50hints").getPrice();

            fifty.setText("50 Hints: " + fiftyhintscost);
            wait.dismiss();
            // update the UI
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d("What Am I? IAB", "Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            } else if (purchase.getSku().equals("50hints")
                    && purchase.getDeveloperPayload().equals(androidid)) {
                // consume the gas and update the UI
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
            fifty.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // provision the in-app purchase to the user
                // (for example, credit 50 gold coins to player's character)
                Toast.makeText(BuyActivity.this,
                        "Purchase Successful - Crediting!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mHelper != null)
            mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at com.liamw.games.whatami.BuyActivity$1.onQueryInventoryFinished(BuyActivity.java:87)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at com.liamw.games.whatami.util.IabHelper$2$1.run(IabHelper.java:533)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-18 19:12:45.829: E/AndroidRuntime(16849):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 87:

```
String fiftyhintscost = inventory.getSkuDetails("50hints").getPrice();
```

Please help me locate the source of the NullPointer and tell me how to fix it...

Comment: So either `inventory` or the result of `getSkuDetails()` is null, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Yeah, but how do I fix it @dmon? It shouldn't be null should it?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong. Are you sure that's the right sku? Check the values in inventory via debug. And don't assume that anything is not null especially when retrieving something from what appears to be a map.

Comment: @dmon Turns out skudetails is null, but the sku is definitely correct...

Comment: @LiamW why don't you debug with a breakpoint on 87 to find out what `inventory` contains.

Comment: @JohnLeehey How do I do that?

Comment: Seems that it contains practically nothing, and the things it does contain are mainly null values @JohnLeehey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you can only use letters in the SKU...

Comment: I don't think this is true.  Specifically from the docs:  Product IDs are unique across an application's namespace. A product ID must start with a lowercase letter or a number, and must be composed using only lowercase letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), underlines (_), and dots (.). The product ID "android.test" is reserved, as are all product IDs that start with "android.test."
In addition, you cannot modify an item's product ID after it is created, and you cannot reuse a product ID.    http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html